# cannot persist destroy to database, can retrieve

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I have a rails app using backbone. In the console, I can create a collection, fetch documents from the server (3) which I confirm by checking length

> > > docs = new Docs();
> > >       docs.fetch();
> > >       docs.length
> > >           3

get one of those docs

> > > d1 = docs.at(0)
> > >           Object { cid=
> > >           "c3"
> > >           , changed={...}, attributes={...}, more...}

destroy the doc

> > > d1.destroy();
> > >           DELETE http: localhost:3000/docs/1
> > >           204 No Content 23ms 
> > >           jquery.js?body=1 (line 8215)
> > >           Object { readyState=
> > >           1
> > >           , setRequestHeader=function(), getAllResponseHeaders=function(), more...}

check the length of docs

```
>>> docs.length

2
```

Create a new collection

> > > docz = new Docs();

get the documents from the server. Note the "304 Not modified message"

> > > docz.fetch();
> > >           GET http:// localhost:3000/docs
> > >           304 Not Modified
> > >                   31ms
> > >           jquery.js?body=1 (line 8215)
> > >           Object { readyState= 
> > >           1
> > >           , setRequestHeader=function(), getAllResponseHeaders=function(), more...}

Check the length. It's 3, when I expected it to be 2.

```
>>> docz.length

3
```

I don't know why when I call destroy I'm getting a no content message if there's clearly 3 records

```
204 No Content
        23ms
```

When I retrieve a record from the database, I have no problem accessing data

```
d.get('title')
>>>"diet book"
```

I have a url set on the model, so I should be able to delete individual records I'd think

```
   url : function() {
       var base = 'docs';
       if (this.isNew()) return base;
       return base + (base.charAt(base.length - 1) == '/' ? '' : '/') + this.id;
    },
```

However, I also can't delete going through a collection `docs.at(0).destroy` has the same effect.

This is my destroy function in the rails controller

```
class DocsController < ApplicationController


    respond_to :json
    ....

   def destroy
     respond_with Doc.find(params[:id])
   end 
end
```

The model

```
 class Doc < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :keywords, :text, :title
 end
```

**Update**
One person who commented on this post noted that I'm supposed to destroy something when I call destroy, but I thought calling destroy on the object destroyed the object

```
d.destroy()  #should destroy d, shouldn't it?
```

This is what I understood from the docs

```
 book.destroy({success: function(model, response) {
  ...
}});
```

Indeed, when I call save() on an object, it saves the object to the database

```
d.save(); #this works, so why not d.destroy();
```

Comment: sorry, forgot to include the opening paragraph. should be better now.

Comment: Shouldn't your `destroy`, well, destroy something?

Comment: @muistooshort  i'm calling it on the object. d.destory(). Therefore destroying the object. How am I supposed to call it? when I create an individual record, I also do it on the ojbect. d.save() which works fine. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Your `destroy` controller method on the server side looks like a `show` since it just sends the `Doc` back. A `destroy` controller should destroy something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this in your Backbone code:

```
d.destroy();
```

you'll trigger a DESTROY request to the server and the client-side model will be destroyed and cleaned up. Your server code will have to deal with the DESTROY request by destroying the server-side model; your `destroy` controller doesn't do that:

```
def destroy
  respond_with Doc.find(params[:id])
end
```

All that does is pull the appropriate `Doc` out of the database and sends it back to the client: your `destroy` controller needs to destroy the server-side model. You need to adjust your controller method to include:

```
doc = Doc.find(params[:id])
doc.destroy
```

A bit of permission checking, error checking, and exception handling on the `find` and `destroy` calls might be a good idea too.

Comment: thanks, it says 500 server error template missing when I put those two lines in the controller. can you tell me how to do the json respond_with on a delete so that it doesn't create that error?

Comment: respond_with Doc.destroy(params[:id])   thanks for your help! found the answer about json response